# boost filesystem segmentation fault in C++11 with ROS

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, boost, ros

My `CMakeLists.txt` includes

```
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
```

And it compiles with the following warnings:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0, needed by /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp.so, may conflict with libboost_filesystem.so.1.64.0
```

And it seg-faults when I run the executable.

Using gdb, I found the cause:

```
Thread 1 "pg_generator" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff762935d in boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*) () from /usr/local/boost/1.64.0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.64.0
```

Seems like boost::filesystem is not working?
Any ideas how to fix this?

I tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and rebooting. (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.)

Comment: GCC broke ABI compatibility for `std::string` when going from gcc4 to gcc5, make sure both boost and your code is compiled with compatibly.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have run into the same problem. 
After a long time debug, I found that we both have done the same thing: we use two versions of boost to build our apps. Well, that's the real problem rather than the conflicts between C++11 and boost.

Because the ros uses boost 1.58, then we'd better use the same boost in other parts of our program. (I use boost 1.60 and you use boost 1.64)

When only one boost version in the program, the problem will be solved.